# Почему жаргон имеет негативный окрас, а сленг - нейтральный?

Tags: жаргон

Предстоит написать реферат на эту тему. Спросил родных и знакомых и заметил, что для них жаргон имеет негативное значение, а сленг - скорее нейтральное. Наверное это отчасти из-за того, что есть выражение "воровской жаргон", при этом нет "воровского сленга". При этом, на мой взгляд, воровской жаргон является скорее арго. Есть ли какие-то источники, которые объясняют это? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Термины арго и жаргон – французские по происхождению (фр. argot, jargon), сленг – английский (англ, slang). Эти термины часто употребляются как синонимы.

Всё это - социальные диалекты, то есть языки групп людей. Языки эти родились и бытуют внутри национальных языков и отличаются специфической лексикой и фразеологией, экспрессивностью оборотов, но не обладают собственной фонетической и грамматической системой.

Иногда различают жаргон, сленг и арго так:
*жаргон обычно имеет профессиональную прикреплённость (жаргон дальнобойщиков, жаргон лётчиков и т.п.)
Арго - не зависит от профессии. Чаще всего это "уличный язык", воровской, феня.
А сленг - это сплав арго с жаргоном и просторечием.*

Другие исследователи утверждают: **Арго** – это, в отличие от жаргона, в той или иной степени **тайный язык, создаваемый специально для того, чтобы сделать речь данной социальной группы непонятной для посторонних.** Поэтому предпочтительнее словосочетания "воровское арго", "арго офеней" – бродячих торговцев в России XIX в., нежели "воровской жаргон", "жаргон офеней". Как считают авторы современного словаря лингвистических терминов, *"...в жаргоне преобладает выражение принадлежности к [данной] группе, в арго – языковая маскировка содержания коммуникации"* [Васильева и др. 1995: 38].

**Жаргон**, в сравнении с арго, является более широким понятием. Это уже не закрытая, а **полузакрытая подсистема.** **Она функционирует в пределах тех же групп (у студентов, военных, воров, подростков), но входящие в нее элементы являются уже более понятными для других носителей русского языка.** Например: «мусор» (полицейский), «обуть» (обмануть), «вертушка» (вертолет), «губа» (гауптвахта).

Что касается такого термина, как **«сленг»**, то его применение связано с более крупными конгломерациями. Поэтому неслучайно особенно часто это слово употребляют в таком словосочетании, как **«молодежный сленг»**. Это уже такая подсистема языка, которая относится к **надгрупповой**. К таким словам относятся, например: «бабки», «балдеть», «крутой», «облом», «дать на лапу», «прикол», «по барабану», «достал», «на шару».

Подробнее на FB.ru: https://fb.ru/article/454818/chto-takoe-argo-znachenie-slova-otlichie-ot-jargona-i-slenga

Можно воспользоваться и следующими материалами: https://studopedia.ru/16_64555_termini-zhargon-argo-i-sleng-problema-ih-razgranicheniya.html

https://vuzlit.ru/921917/razgranichenie_ponyatiy_zhargon_argo_sleng

https://studopedia.su/10_25293_argo-zhargon-sleng.html

https://thedifference.ru/chem-otlichaetsya-zhargon-ot-slenga/

Comment: Спасибо! Вы мне помогли.

Comment: Я рада, что помогла, но что же Вы не приняли ответ, нажав на галочку под треугольником внизу?

Comment: Забыл, извините)